# what does a comma mean when doing a sum in python

Tags: python, rounding

what does the comma mean in the below sum

```
BMI = round(weight/(height*height),2)
```

A persons BMI is being calculated but I do not understand why the comma is being used and what it means

Comment: 2 is the second argument to `round` which is the number of digits: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: There is no sum here.

Comment: @rdas You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The round function takes two parameters. The first is the number that's being rounded. The second is to how many digits the number will be rounded.
`round(254.8932, 2)` will round to 254.89 because the 2 makes it round to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a function in python, you can have multiple "arguments". Arguments are the inputs. So for example, you have the function `round()` and two inputs to it: `weight/(height*height)` and `2`. The comma separates these arguments if you have more than one argument. You can see more about the function `round()` here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round